# Advanced Master Theorem?

Tags: reference-request, master-theorem

I have learned the Master's Theorem from the CLRS textbook (2nd Edition), the form of the Master Theorem given in the above text is associated with the proof of each and every case. So at the end I know how it works and it also explains the intuition behind the same.

The form of Master Theorem given in CLRS is as follows:

> (Master theorem) Let $a \geqslant 1$ and $b > 1$ be constants, let $f(n)$ be a function, and let $T (n)$ be deﬁned on the nonnegative integers by the recurrence
>
> $T(n) = aT(n/b)+ f (n)$ ;
>
> where we interpret $n/b$ to mean either $\lceil b/n \rceil$ or $\lfloor b/n \rfloor$. Then $T(n)$ has the following asymptotic bounds:
>
> 1. If $f(n)=O (n^{log_ba - \epsilon})$ for some constant $\epsilon > 0$, then $T(n)=\Theta (n^{log_ba})$.
> 2. If $f(n)=\Theta (n^{log_ba})$, then $T(n)=\Theta (n^{log_ba}lg n)$
> 3. If $f(n)=\Omega (n^{log_ba + \epsilon})$ for some constant $\epsilon > 0$, and if $af(n/b) \leqslant cf(n)$ for some constant $c < 1$ and all sufﬁciently large n, then $T(n)=\Theta (f(n))$.

Now there is also a version of Master Theorem which is claimed as The Advanced Master Theorem by few sources on the web and also they claim that this version is more powerful than the one in the CLRS text.

> $T(n) = aT(n/b)+\theta(n^{k}log^{p}n)$
>
> where $n$ = size of the problem
>
> $a$ = number of subproblems in the recursion and $a \geqslant 1$
>
> $n/b$ = size of each subproblem
>
> $b > 1 , k \geqslant 0$ and $p$ is a real number.
>
> Then,
>
> 1. if $a > b^{k}$, then $T(n) = θ(n^{log_ba})$
> 2. if $a = b^{k}$, then
>
>    - if $p > -1$, then $T(n) = θ(n^{log_ba} log^{p+1}n)$
>    - if $p = -1$, then $T(n) = θ(n^{log_ba} log log n)$
>    - if $p < -1$, then $T(n) = θ(n^{log_ba})$
> 3. if $a < b^{k}$, then
>
>    - if $p \geqslant 0$, then $T(n) = θ(n^{k} log^{p}n)$
>    - if $p < 0$, then $T(n) = θ(n^{k})$

I could not find a text from where this has been taken, as a result I do not even know whether it is valid or not and without knowing its validity it shall be dangerous to apply it. If anyone has encountered the second version of the theorem, it shall be helpful if the name of the standard text book from which this second version has been given, is shared here. I want a proof of the second version of the Master Theorem if at all it exits and if so a one to one correspondence between the cases of the theorem given in the CLRS and that in the second version. Moreover the second version seems have used $\theta$ instead of $\Theta$ and if that is the case the second version only seems to  cover case $2$ of the CLRS version which has $f(n) = \Theta(...)$

Comment: Have you consulted Wikipedia?

Comment: Yes I did and it is among those websites which deals with this second version to some extent not exactly though. In Wikipedia they deal with an extension of the 2nd case in CLRS when $f(n)=\Theta(n^{log_ba}log^{k}n)$ which matches with the second case of the 2nd version. But all other cases of CLRS does not involve $\Theta$ in $f(n)$ and hence I do not know to what cases of the CLRS the 1st and 2nd cases of the extended version maps on to. In the reference portion of wiki, they say CLRS and Goodrich and Tamassia(which covers only the k>=0 situation in case 2 extended of CLRS(ex 4.6-2)).

Comment: The Notes section given, I am unable to access many of the papers(may be I need to buy them? I have no idea about them) but from those documents which could be accessed in the notes section, only the CLRS version (and to some extent the extended form of the case 2 as given in ex 4.6-2 of CLRS) is dealt with. No hardcore proof or even the exact statement of the second version or its intuition was found by me in the resources available to me..

Comment: There’s no difference between $\theta$ and $\Theta$.

Comment: Now for the 1st case of the 2nd version, $a>b^{k}$ => $k<log_ba$ => $k=log_ba - \epsilon$ so the exponent of $n$ match with that of case 1 of CLRS but there is mismatch at the notation of $\theta$(in version 2) and $O$ in version 1. Moreover there is an extra $log^{p}n$ in version 2. Now if $f(n)=\Theta(n^{log_ba-\epsilon}log^{p}n)$ then it is not equivalent to $f(n)=O(n^{log_ba-\epsilon})$ I hope, However the results in both the cases match, But the 3rd case of the two version does not seem to match, neither in the form of $f(n)$ nor in the result of $T(n)$

Comment: There is a paper of Chee Yap linked to on Wikipedia: https://cs.nyu.edu/exact/doc/master.pdf. Have you seen it?

Comment: Also, you can typically derive the consequences of the master theorem from Akra–Bazzi.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks for the paper, it seems to have a lot of details regarding the topic and previously I was unable to access it as I was clicking the first link which redirected me to some payment page...

Comment: Actually, the link I gave is available from the SemanticScholar link, under "[PDF]" (next to the paywalled link).

Comment: I went through the paper of Chee Yap, few things which I could make out are:(1)I could only find a match of version 2 case 2 sub cases (i) and (ii). The regularity condition which he talks about(case +) maps with the case (3) of CLRS but the third case in the version 2, which is a potential candidate for match with the CLRS case(3) has two cases for p<0 and p>=0 while none such subcases in Yap's or CLRS's... Ultimate conclusion is, I still not get an answer :(

Comment: Perfection is hard to attain...